# Official PHP Doc public methods declared with ::

Tags: php

Why are public functions in the official PHP Docs declared with a normaly static function "::" tag.
Example:

```
public DateInterval DateTime::diff ( DateTimeInterface $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = false ] )
```

[DateTime Ref of PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php)

What is the meaning behind this declaration in the official php docs?

Comment: It just means that `diff` is a method of `DateTime`. It's just how it is represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're documenting PHP it's hard to describe the relationship of a function to it's class. So they use the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) to indicate that the method is part of that class. This is for the sake of documentation ONLY.

It does NOT necessarily mean that the function is static. Consider [the mysqli function list](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Almost none of those methods are static. If you read the [class defintion](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) you can see this. Also, a static method will say so in the documentation. For instance [mysqli::poll](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php)

```
public static int mysqli::poll ( array &$read , array &$error , array &$reject , int $sec [, int $usec ] )
```

Answer (score -1):

It's mean DateTime has static method diff and that method return variable DateInterval type.

Comment: `DateTime::diff` is not a static method